# How to download URL instead of opening it with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a PDF and outputting it using Ajax

Here is the output on success:

```
window.location.replace(json['download_link']);
```

However, I want to prompt a download instead of opening up the file itself. Is it this straightforward?

Comment: have you tried `window.location.href = json['download_link'];`? I think that will download the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your html where you want the download link to appear.

```
<a download="file" id="downloadlink" style="display: none">Download</a>
```

Then in your success add the following.

```
// Get the hidden download link
var link = document.getElementById('downloadlink');
// Set the link to the json response
link.href = json['download_link'];
// Unhide the link
link.style.display = 'block';
```

Comment: Thank you, perfect, I will give it as answer in 10 mins

Comment: Note that the `download` attribute is not supported in IE or Safari: http://caniuse.com/#feat=download

Comment: Interesting, maybe you have a newer version than they tested. That's good though.